# Photoview disable zoom out of image

Tags: android, android-photoview

- I am using [Photoview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library in my Android app to enable image zoom-in functionality.
- But I want to disable image  zoom out. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to disable this functionality
but all you can do is use "minScale" functionality
as i used in my code
below is the example

```
     PhotoView(
        minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 1.0,
        imageProvider: const NetworkImage(
          "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1708936/pexels-photo-1708936.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Where to add this code @Vismay

Comment: PhotoView is a WIdget you can add Photoview in column, row, container or sizedbox